# What does it mean for a CORS preflight request to be chained to its target resource

Tags: java, jetty, cors

I am working on configuring CORS for a Jetty Servlet, and find that some XHR requests are denied at preflight. I have set the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and according to the Jetty docs for [CrossOriginFilter](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html) the default Access-Control-Allow Origin header is "*". So everything should be permitted through.

There is another filter option that I am having trouble finding information about:

> **chainPreflight**
>   if true preflight requests are chained to their target resource for
>   normal handling (as an OPTION request). Otherwise the filter will
>   response to the preflight. Default is true.

What does it mean for the filter to "response to the preflight"? What does it mean for a request to be chained to their target? Most of the resources I have found about this option use the exact same phrasing and don't offer any further explanation.

In [this stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697371/1279340), the writer says:

> Notes: CrossOriginFilter has a parameter, chainPreflight, that is set to true by default. This needs to be set to false. This was the key to CORS forwarding POST instead of OPTIONS to SOLR.. Also, order matters!

While I am not building a Solr app, I am wondering if this is where I am going wrong with my configuration. Any help to understand this option better would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `chainPreflight` option is set to true (as it is by default), then the CrossOriginFilter will add the required access control headers, and pass the request on to the endpoint for further handling. The target endpoint should have some logic for handling the preflight request.

If the `chainPreflight` option is false, then the CrossOriginFilter will add the required access control headers and respond to the request directly.

Check out [my blog post](http://katieleonard.ca/blog/2016/preflight-check-with-cors-chainpreflight-option/) for an illustration.

Comment: Great blog post. I love the little diagram ! :) - I kind of came to the same conclusion from reading docs. But it's great to find a confirmation of that reasoning. - For me also chainPreflight=false seems to make most sense in my application.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had a hard-time wrapping my head around the docs, and drawing always helps :)